# The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I try to do Razor ContosoUniversity (renamed in ContsoObserve initally) for Visual Studio 2017 and get error 
my .csproj is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I installed all that packages in NuGet

and when I

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Student -dc SchoolContext -udl -outDir Pages\Students --referenceScriptLibraries
```

get

> Build FAILED. 
>     Data\SchoolContext.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\About.cshtml.cs(5,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\Contact.cshtml.cs(5,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\Error.cshtml.cs(6,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\Index.cshtml.cs(6,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Program.cs(7,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Program.cs(8,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Program.cs(9,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(5,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Builder' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(6,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(7,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(10,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\About.cshtml.cs(9,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Program.cs(39,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IWebHost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Data\SchoolContext.cs(10,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(21,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\Contact.cshtml.cs(9,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(33,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IApplicationBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(33,56): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IHostingEnvironment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Data\SchoolContext.cs(16,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbSet<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Startup.cs(16,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\Error.cshtml.cs(10,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Data\SchoolContext.cs(17,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbSet<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Data\SchoolContext.cs(18,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbSet<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Data\SchoolContext.cs(20,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Data\SchoolContext.cs(20,33): error CS0115: 'SchoolContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Pages\Index.cshtml.cs(10,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       Data\SchoolContext.cs(12,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbContextOptions<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>           0 Warning(s)
>           28 Error(s)
>   I try unload and reload project. Same result.

I add 
    
and errors count decrease

> Build FAILED.
>
> Data\SchoolContext.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\About.cshtml.cs(5,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\Contact.cshtml.cs(5,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\Error.cshtml.cs(6,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\Index.cshtml.cs(6,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'RazorPages' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Startup.cs(10,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\About.cshtml.cs(9,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Data\SchoolContext.cs(10,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\Contact.cshtml.cs(9,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\Error.cshtml.cs(10,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Data\SchoolContext.cs(16,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'DbSet<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Pages\Index.cshtml.cs(10,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'PageModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Data\SchoolContext.cs(17,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'DbSet<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Data\SchoolContext.cs(18,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'DbSet<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Data\SchoolContext.cs(20,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'ModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Data\SchoolContext.cs(20,33): error CS0115:
>   'SchoolContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method
>   found to override
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>   Data\SchoolContext.cs(12,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'DbContextOptions<>' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj]
>       0 Warning(s)

Comment: Have you done ``dotnet restore`` to get all the nuget packages?

Comment: yes. of cource. I add     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" /> and errors count turn from 28 to 17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` (currently verrsion 2.0.3). That will include Entity Framework (plus more than you will need).

Also, don't use `Update` on the `PackageReference` element, use `Include`.

Comment: The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.4' was not found.

  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:

      \

  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0.4'.

Comment: @ifooi i dont know what you changed?

Comment: Yes, I add Microsoft.AspNetCore.All but Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.4 remains. Do I need to uninstall it?

Comment: just have the single `PackageReference`.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.3 to 2.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 ContosoObserve -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 2.0.1 -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.3) 
 ContosoObserve -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0) ContosoObserve C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj 1

Comment: I reinstall all projects and I have No executable found matching command "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"

Comment: @ifooi try `dotnet restore`

Comment: I always do It!

Comment: Restore completed in 83,71 ms for C:\Users\STR\source\repos\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve\ContosoObserve.csproj.

Comment: No executable found matching command "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"

Comment: O, nice all works! a removed <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup> and now I add it again

Comment: My .csprojis <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message even though I have already installed "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" on Visual Studio 2019. I did uninstall & reinstall and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your IDE is Visual studio 2017 or 2019, Go to the Nuget package manager, search and install the package(s) that start with the words Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore they are about 3 packages in number. The errors will disappear