# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore will not reference in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I've downloaded the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` with the nuget manager extension, but whenever I try referencing it

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

it won't accept the namespace.

> The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [Program]csharp(CS0234)

I've tried downloading the package in the CLI, and I've tried older version of the library, but nothing really changes.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098261/the-type-or-namespace-name-entityframeworkcore-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098261/the-type-or-namespace-name-entityframeworkcore-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace)

Comment: Sadly no, I've tried what was posted, but I till recieve the same error. Thank you however!